# Use of _spawnlp in VB6

Tags: windows, com, vb6, spawn

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/20y988d2.aspx) for `spawnlp` says:

> Files that are open when a _spawn call is made remain open in the new process.
>
> The _spawn functions can pass all information about open files, including the translation mode, to the new process. This information is passed in real mode through the C_FILE_INFO entry in the environment. The startup code normally processes this entry and then deletes it from the environment. However, if a _spawn function spawns a non-C process, this entry remains in the environment.

Does this mean that if a VB6 program calls `_spawnlp(_P_OVERLAY,`... to restart itself and then exits; then file handles from the original process remain open and completely inaccessible?

Is there a better method in VB6 for a process to exit and restart itself than having it `spawn` and wait for the child to succeed before exiting? (e.g. call `CreateProcess` direclty without the flag to inherit file handles)

(Background: my in-process COM server is used by a VB6 program and I have the problem that they spawn without unloading my DLL, so the newly-spawned process fails to move a file during startup because the old process still has a handle on the file).

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing that the original process is left around (even if it's exited) until all handles to it are closed?

Comment: @Deanna I check with Process Explorer for handles on my file, and it shows the old and new process both have a handle, even before the new process loads my DLL. I see "Process Exit" in Process Monitor for the old process pretty quickly after spawning the new process.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but process exit doesn't necessarily mean that all information about it is cleared up if something else is holding a handle to that process.

Comment: Just [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(v=vs.60).aspx) the second instance with appropriate command line, and then [`End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243356(v=vs.60).aspx) the first instance? Unless there are other complications that you haven't mentioned yet...